# Как сделать автоматическую прогрузку страницы?

Tags: c#, xnet

Здравствуйте, собственно суть дела такова - есть метод, считывающий друзей пользователя в вконтакте. я заношу в массив строк id людей, к которым нужно зайти и считать список, но программа считывает список друзей только у первого пользователя, а остальных не прогружает, почему? делаю вот так:

```
public string [] FRIENDS_SEARCH()
        {
            List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
            string[] logins = File.ReadAllText("D:/ГРУППЫ/БАЗА ДАННЫХ/Город/БД.txt").Split(' ');
            for (int o = 0; o < logins.Length; o++)
            {
                string lgn = logins[o];

                var request = new HttpRequest();
                request.UserAgent = HttpHelper.ChromeUserAgent();
                request.Cookies = cook;
                request.AddParam("act", "filter_friends");
                request.AddParam("age_from", "0");
                request.AddParam("age_to", "0");
                request.AddParam("al", "1");

                request.AddParam("city", "374");
                request.AddParam("sex", "0");
                request.AddParam("uid", lgn);


                HttpResponse response = request.Post("https://vk.com/friends");

                string[] t = response.ToString().Split('"');
                for (int i = 1; i < t.Length; i++)
                    if (t[i].Length > 5)
                        tmp.Add("id" + t[i]);   
            }
            return tmp.ToArray();
        }
```

подключена библиотека xNet

Comment: А Вы уверены что Logins.length > 1 ?

Comment: да, в отладчике проверял

Comment: Что-то мне код `response.ToString().Split('"')` кажется подозрительным.

Comment: ну считывание происходит успешно, список друзей возвращается, но новая страница не прогружается

Comment: @inkorpus: Ну, если с _этой_ функцией всё в порядке, тогда покажите код, с которым проблема.

Comment: вы мой вопрос прочли внимательно? код возвращает список друзей как надо. request.AddParam("uid", lgn); - вот в этой строке вставляется id человека из массива строк, на которого надо перейти и считать людей, но переход на новую страницу не происходит. почему?

Comment: @Чад, всё таки Logins.length = 1 у меня, как-то это можно исправить?

Comment: @inkorpus, Приведите пример файла БД.txt. Скорее всего у Вас не правильно разбивается файл в массив